# custom dimension using dimensional-tf

Tags: haskell

I'm using `dimensional` with custom units ('Numerics.Units.Dimensional.Extensible'). However, it's based on functional dependency and  I'm encountering `UndecidableInstances` issue. I could solve my problem using `dimensional-tf` which is uses type family instead of functional dependecy.
However I didn't find any equivalent to `Extensible` in `dimensional-tf`. As it not been implemented yet or is it just not necessary. If that's the case, how can I define user defined unit in `dimensional-tf` ?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/units uses `TypeFamilies` and it seems to support custom units. But there are still plenty of `UndecidableInstances` in that library (and probably in user code too), so it doesn't really answer your question.